# Code returns TypeError: task.style is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner building a todo list app in vanilla JS. Im trying to create function that filters through the todo items and displays the items the are either completed , in-completed or All task but im running into the error

> task.style is undefined"

```
const filterTask = document.querySelector('.filter-options'); //select tag in HTML which allows user to select whether they want to display the completed or in-completed task

const todoUl = document.querySelector('.todo-ul'); //the ul under which the tasks become childNodes

filterTask.addEventListener('click', filterTodo)

function filterTodo(e) {
    const tasks = todoUl.childNodes;
    tasks.forEach((task) => {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all-task":
                task.style.display = "flex";
                break;
            case "completed-task":
                if (task.classList.contains('completed-task')) {
                    task.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    task.style.display = "none";
                }
        }
    })
```

```html
<select class="filter-options">
  <option value="all-task">All Task</option>
  <option value="completed-task">Completed Task</option>
  <option value="uncompleted-task">Uncompleted Task</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You must be accessing task.style somewhere. Can you share complete code with html?

Comment: Task will probably not be an html element, log the task object and analyze what it is. You can only set a style on an object that supports this.

Comment: @Rmaxx task does indeed return an html element. When I log task it returns the div which contains the to-do task

Comment: Its not be an html object with a style prop, but a node like  Mosh says.

Answer (score 0):

`childNodes` returns `NodeList` which is a collection of nodes. The issue here that this collection contains not only [`Element`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) but also [`Text` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text). `Text` node doesn't have `style` property, therefor it's `undefined`.

Instead using `childNodes`, use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) which returns only `Element`s.

The difference between `childNodes` and `children`.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const childNodes = [...ul.childNodes].map(node => node.nodeName);
const children = [...ul.children].map(node => node.nodeName);

console.log(`childNodes nodes [${childNodes.join()}]`);
console.log(`children nodes [${children.join()}]`);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```